# Unity rotation.eulerAngles.x not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The only debug log is "Debug.Log(head.rotation.eulerAngles.x.ToString());" and the head is the selected object. Why I get 352 and not -49?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBGuh.jpg)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your post more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that the inspector is relative to the object's local space, while `Transform.rotation` is relative to world space.

Then, even with `Transform.localRotation`, getting from `EulerAngles` will return a value in the 0-360 range. The inspector has it's own value, and just transposes that to the object's transform.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand.
If I rotate the object by 90° the number is changing in the inspector but what the console writes me don't change that much

Comment: @BalázsBerecz Updated the answer. For anything further than that, you're going to have to explain what are you rotating, where, and how.